# Airflow on Kubernetes add additional provider like SnowflakeOperator

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am using Airflow 2.2.4 installed on EKS via the official helm chart and uses KubernetesPodOperator.
Now I want to add SnowflakeOperator to my task. Following the guide [here](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/extra-python-packages.md) I created a custom airflow image like the below and hosted it in an ECR repo

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.4-python3.8
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==3.1.0
```

I am then trying to customize the helm installation by passing the above ECR repo in values.yml file like below:

```
defaultAirflowRepository: xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sophia/custom-airflow-image

images:
  airflow:
    repository: "xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/airflow-deploy/custom-airflow-image"
    tag: airflow-app-deploy
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Here is the helm command I am using:

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --version v1.5.0 --namespace sophia-airflow --values /tmp/airflow/airflow.yaml
```

But for some reason, these values are not taken into consideration by the helm while installation. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: which image you find when you call the command `kubectl describe pod <scheduler pod>`?

Comment: The issue was the values.yml file was cached in Jenkins and did not reflect the latest values. Added `deleteDir()` step in the Jenkins stage and the issue is resolved